# Is there any solution for this pip problem?

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, pip, package

[image: cmder Pip call]

i can not use Pip
i have copied the get-pip.py file in the python directory and call it from cmder by "python get-pip.py but when after i the got this response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is its not in path. You can add it to windows path using what is in this question: [Adding a directory to the PATH environment variable in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-a-directory-to-the-path-environment-variable-in-windows)
You can see the path that should be added in the response. Its something like C:\Users\willi\python\Scripts